# Saving JSON in Postgres table with Fluent

Tags: json, swift, postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm looking for a recommendation for how to go about capturing the entire JSON body from a request and save it, along with some of the JSON contents, to a PSQL table. I have a column defined for the json:

```
.field(.string("json"), .json)
```

and I'm trying to save the data into the db but I can't seem to satisfy the .json type requirement. I continue to see this error:

> server: column "json" is of type jsonb but expression is of type bytea (transformAssignedExpr)

when using this to convert the JSON:

```
if let reqData: Data = req.body.string?.data(using: .utf8) {
     try await Scan.query(on: req.db)
          .set(\.$json, to: reqData)
          .filter(\.$unitId == unitID)
          .update()
}
```

I'm certain the issue lies within the way I'm casting the `req.body.string?.data(using: .utf8)` and I've been fiddling with some of the other methods within the Request class and can't figure out if there is a built-in method for this or if I'm going to need to do some more work to perform a conversion. I have been looking for some resources on this and I'm having a tough time finding more information on what a common practice is for this.

I also attempted initially to use a jsonb type but to keep things simple I'm sticking with the json type for now since jsonb isn't really supported in Fluent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching for an easy way to do this, it appears that the only way to make this work is to: decode the entire JSON into a custom data type (swift model, not Fluent model) that accurately represents the JSON structure and conforms to `PostgresJSONBCodable` or `PostgresJSONCodable` depending on how you want to store it.

Once you have that data storage mechanism, you will decode the JSON into that (swift) model and then encode it into a `PostgresData(jsonb: <#T##Data#>)` and then make your db query to update the db.

This poses a significant challenge to handling dynamic JSON queries where the structure is unknown, but thankfully that is not the case here and I can rigidly define the data structure. This is sort of a common theme across Swift apps due to the nature of Swift and isn't necessarily a detractor if you value stability and speed.

I am using pieces of information found from these sources to make this determination:

- https://forums.swift.org/t/vapor-4-and-fluent-how-to-add-a-postgres-jsonb-column/34565
- https://losingfight.com/blog/2018/11/25/how-to-add-a-postgresql-jsonb-column-in-vapors-fluent/
- https://githubhelp.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver

Comment: Ok so for now, I've decided to just store the JSON as a bytea type in the postgres db until I can build out the functionality to encode the model into a json type. Also I've learned that the PostgresData type is going to be deprecated and shouldn't be implemented in new code. 

I just changed my migration code to make this change:

.field("json", .custom("bytea"))